# Function or expression cannot be used in the check clause

Tags: mariadb, check-constraints

I have problems with check constraints in mariadb 10.3.6.

For example, with this table:

```
create or replace table usuarios (
    cedula int not null,
    contraseña varchar(15) not null,
    nombre varchar(15) not null,
    apellido varchar(15) not null);
```

And with these functions:

```
create function contr_usuario(dato varchar(15)) returns int
begin
    return(select dato regexp '^[[:alnum:]]*$');
end;//

create function nom_apell_usuario(dato varchar(25)) returns int
begin
    return (select dato regexp '^[[:alpha:]]*$|(^[[:alpha:]]+[ ]+ 
    [[:alpha:]]*$)');
end;//
```

I try this:

```
alter table usuarios
add constraint pk_usuarios primary key (cedula);

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_cedula check (500000 <= cedula and cedula <= 10000000);

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_contraseña check (contr_usuario(contraseña) = 1);

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_nom_usuario check (nom_apell_usuario(nombre) = 1);

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_apell_usuario check (nom_apell_usuario(apellido) = 1);
```

But it doesn't work and I get these errors:

```
ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 138 in file: '/media/sf_marcelo/projects/control_financiero/sql_scripts/db_finanza.sql': Function or expression '`contr_usuario`()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `ck_contraseña`
ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 140 in file: '/media/sf_marcelo/projects/control_financiero/sql_scripts/db_finanza.sql': Function or expression '`nom_apell_usuario`()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `ck_nom_usuario`
ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 142 in file: '/media/sf_marcelo/projects/control_financiero/sql_scripts/db_finanza.sql': Function or expression '`nom_apell_usuario`()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `ck_apell_usuario`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.079 sec)
```

So, how can I make the check constraints if functions and expressions are not allowed?

Obs: previously I tried this with mariadb 10.1, even though the same code ran without problems when I inserted data the check constraints didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your functions only consist of one expression, you can pull that expression directly into the check constraints expressions.

```
alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_contraseña check (contraseña regexp '^[[:alnum:]]*$');

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_nom_usuario check (nombre regexp '^[[:alpha:]]*$|(^[[:alpha:]]+[ ]+[[:alpha:]]*$)');

alter table usuarios
add constraint ck_apell_usuario check (apellido regexp '^[[:alpha:]]*$|(^[[:alpha:]]+[ ]+[[:alpha:]]*$)');
```